# How to suppress deleting "target" dir on "mvn clean"

Tags: maven

Is it possible to suppress deleting default **target** directory during **mvn clean**? Current process deletes entire directory with all its content while I need to keep empty dir on delete.

I guess I will be able to set such configiration by using `<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>`, but still there remains the implicit process of the **mvn clean** which deletes entire directory anyway.

Comment: First if you don't like to delete the `target` directory don't call `mvn clean` use `mvn verify` or `mvn test` etc. instead? And why do you need to keep an empty direcotry ? Why what is the problem here ? Please elaborate more in detail what you real problem is?

Comment: Actully I depend on ```mvn clean``` because there are more tasks called here. I need to keep ```target``` directory undeleted becasue I want to use symlink for this directory. Removing the direcotry removes the symlink and I would be forced to recreate it agian before other build.

Comment: Why using symlinks? For what purpose? What is the real problem ? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? What tasks are called there? That sounds wrong... please make a full example... that's best to understand your problem...

Comment: @JanStanicek That really sounds like you are on the wrong track ... there is probably a much better solution for your original problem.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I want to have ```target``` mapped on the ramdisk due to performance reasons. Ramdisk solution works for me, it gives me more than 50% performance gain on build and also 10% in runtime. The only issue was to provide some automation without manual recreating of ```target``` dir.

Comment: Wait, so where does the symlink come into place? It's adding to a lot of confusion in this thread. I assume you don't need symlinks for working with ramdisk (not on Windows here).

Comment: @JanStanicek Interesting. What kind of Ramdisk do you use? How does the mapping work?

Comment: @Alex I am not aware of any solution how to use ramdisk without symlinks with standard mvn directory structure.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I use ImDisk and the created memory disk is destination of my symlink named target. Symlink is on the place of regular target dir in project.

Comment: @JanStanicek I have not understood yet why you just override `project.build.directory` with the directory in the RAM disk.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Because `mvn clean` will still delete it?

Comment: What other tasks did you integrate into `mvn clean` and why?

Comment: @JFabianMeier other task are related to generate-sources result outside the target dir. This is not my decision and I don't know the reason. I need to stick with default structure because this project is only small piece of larger infrastructure and other parts depends on it. The change described in "question" is the simplest and the most straightforward. If you feel that it should be done in different way please provide an "answer" and elaborate the solution. Also for others with different usecases

Comment: The main purpose of `mvn clean` is to delete the content of the target dir. It would be strange to call `clean` and leave everything as it is, just running unrelated other tasks.

Comment: Right. I do follow this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can make use of [excludeDefaultDirectories](https://github.com/apache/maven-clean-plugin/blob/maven-clean-plugin-3.2.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/clean/CleanMojo.java#L169): set it to **true** and manually list the subdirectories you want to purge via [filesets](https://github.com/apache/maven-clean-plugin/blob/maven-clean-plugin-3.2.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/clean/CleanMojo.java#L117). I haven't tested this but it should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yep, this worked. The ```target``` directory remian untouched.

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>                
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
        <filesets>
          <fileset>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/target/</directory>
            <includes><include>**/*</include></includes>
          </fileset>
        </filesets>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

Sorry, I am not able to format the text in the comment.

Comment: Nice! Taking this further, replace `${project.basedir}/target/` with `${project.build.directory}` (afaik, the trailing slash is superfluous).

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic link on Linux (as for other Unix-variants) uses its *name*, not the actual directory to resolve where it points.  You can then use `ls -P` on BSD-variants like MacOS or `ls -L` on GNU variants (untested) to see what is pointed to.

The information stored in a symbolic link does not get invalidated when `target` is deleted, so when the directory is created again the symbolic link will work again.

On my Mac:

```bash
ravn@freewifi demo % mkdir target; ln -s target t
ravn@freewifi demo % ls -lP t
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ravn  staff  6 30 Jun 18:40 t -> target
ravn@freewifi demo % ls -l t/
total 0
ravn@freewifi demo % rmdir target; ls -l t/
ls: t/: No such file or directory
ravn@freewifi demo % mkdir target; ls -l t/
total 0
ravn@freewifi demo %
```

The trailing slash is to ensure that the symbolic link is followed (or at least tried to).

Comment: seems to me off-topic. Maybe there is a little bit misunderstood. I want to symlink/junction named ```target``` which will be fully compatible with maven and the destination should be elsewhere. Removing/adding destination works, but removing the symlink itself won't work. At least on Win10. Maybe Mac or Unix is different.

Comment: @JanStanicek does windows 10 have symbolic links these days? Anyways, this sound more and more like an X-Y problem to me.